# Event max in slider jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, events

The events for slider in jquery ui are create,start,slide,change and stop

how can i do for have a event when the user arrive to the max value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the [slide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide) event and check if the current slider value is equal to its `max` option:

```
$("#yourSlider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == $(this).data("ui-slider").options.max) {
            // Slider has reached maximum value.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sire it works? I tried this and got **undefined** on console.log($(this).data("slider"))

Comment: @Thompson, you're right, this solution does not work anymore since [jQuery UI 1.9 changed the key used to access the widget instance through `data()`](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys). I did a series of updates at the time, but I apparently missed this answer. The revised version should work properly on jQuery UI 1.9+. Thank you for bringing this to my attention :)